# What is $? var in script below on condition of while loop

Tags: shell, unix, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
host google.com>/dev/null
while [  $? -ne 0 ];
do
sleep 3
done
say "You are now connected to internet"
```

I guess $? is associated with google.com>/dev/null, making the logic work, but i am interested in detail description on $?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$?` is the result (return value) of previously executed command.

Comment: yes a kind of Alberto :).. i googled but could not figure it out..

Comment: @Sakthi To be pedantic, `$?` is the exit value of the most recently executed pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the info @WilliamPursell. I missed out the pipe:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this will sound pedantic, but `$?` is not a variable, it is a value.  `?` is the name of the variable, placing `$` at the front gives the value.

Now you can search for `?` in `man bash`:

*Expands to the exit status of the most recently  executed  foreground pipeline.*

It is often tested unnecessarily.  `if` and `while` statements in `bash` (and most shells) test for success(true) or failure(false).  Success is where the value of `?` is 0, and failure when it is some other number (which has the range 1-255).  `!` means "not", as in many languages, and inverts the truth:

```
while ! host google.com>/dev/null
do
    sleep 3
done
echo "You are now connected to internet"
```

(I had to use `echo`, not sure where `say` comes from, Perl?)

Comment: Note that the example given in this answer changes the semantics of the code (it changes them to be correct).  In the code of the question, the success of the `host` command is checked only once.  Each subsequent evaluation of `$?` is checking the return status of `sleep`!

Comment: @cdarke unnecessary testing on while happened because of lack of knowledge on $?.. now i got it and thanks for making it clear . and one more thing, say is Mac Os X specific text to speech command..